# Browser redirects to router login page

Tags: router

I have a Netgear Nighthawk R7000 that has been working fine.
This morning we started having a problem - Any browser (Firefox, Explorer, Edge, Chrome, etc.) on any device (PC / Phone / Tablet) on the network is re-directed to the Router login page whenever we try to access any web page.
Is this a virus or something in the router?

Comment: No, it probably doesn't mean a virus on the router. Start by rebooting your modem, turning your router off and then back on after the modem has come up, and then restarting any other devices connected to your network.

Comment: Often a router will redirect all traffic sent through it to its logon page in order to "help" a user set it up for the first time. Then, once configured it no longer intercepts the traffic. This may suggest your router's configuration was accidentally reset.  Check the config and set it up/fix settings as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the suggestions, here is what I found.
When I logged in to my router I saw a warning message about traffic approaching the monthly limit.
That is when I remembered I had recently enabled the traffic meter on the router with the option to 'Pop up a warning message' when traffic approached the monthly limit.
I reset the limit and the re-direct stopped.

It appears that the router can only display the pop-up message if you're logged in to the router.
This is bad enough for the administrator who may not understand what is happening but even worse for other users who have no access to the router login info.

Comment: Not sure why it's downvoted, I had a similar issue. Router wanted an update and was redirecting all http requests to the login page. I couldn't figure it out because indeed there was no message unless you log in, and this answer helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I have had similar redirect of URLs to routerlogin.net on a NetGear WNR1000v3 WiFi Router. Also seeming randomly chosen URLs, while others worked fine. Oddly I could sometimes go thru Google and link to URL that was being redirected when entered directly in browser. But others would redirect no matter what I tried.

As well, logging in to router was redirected to routerlogin.net/update... so could not find or fix problem.  But for some reason when I would reset the device (NOT to Factory) it would work for some seemingly random time.

That's where YOU GUYS HELPED when you mentioned traffic message popup.  AND INDEED after more work getting past that redirect on login I was able to turn off that traffic monitoring and now have no issues with URLs without redirect. THANKS

After DAYS of fighting, and trying to get past the login redirect to shut OFF traffic monitor to even see if that was my issue.  And after trying many different devices, paths, I finally had a rabbit popup as I was going to sleep to unplug all but PC (so little traffic) and reset router and retry login- NO JOY with PC wired or Smartphone wireless. Back to try sleep AND Rabbit said TRY BYPASSING Router and I WAS ABLE to logon when used smartphone and 3G web access (android/chrome). BUT logged in BUT THERE WAS TRAFFIC MESSAGE displaying and could not get past it (at first).

HOWEVER I modified the URL showing in chrome after login (routerlogin.net/traffic???update) to "routerlogin.net/start.htm" (Luckily I had remembered that from way back when) and the login held and God Bless, I able to enter normal router start webpage.

I THEN VERY CAREFULLY (tiny arse buttons) navigated to the Advanced - Advanced... Traffic page and unchecked the radio box for traffic monitoring and then logged out.

Back on PC I tried to log back in using routerlogin.net and got some OTHER redirect to help page about trying to fix cache etc and did all that but still nojoy, BUT I WAS able to login to router now with direct IP (e.g. 192.168.1.1/start.htm) which was different as this did not work prior to traffic kill.  I stayed long enough to verify changes were still good and then started to go to website URLs that would fail no matter the 'state' of the Netgear Router.  ALL WORKED !

Now over 36 hours since removing traffic monitoring I have had NO redirect problems on websites after a MARATHON session working on backlog.   Before killing the traffic monitor I was getting redirects happening after going to only a few sites.

Anyway my two cents - you helped me get on this path - so hope this helps someone else..

Answer (score 0):

What ended up working for me was using Chrome's incognito mode to keep it from using cookies or anything then going to http://192.168.1.1/BRS_index.htm
"192.168.1.1" being the default IP it has from a factory reset. IDK it may work using it's regular LAN IP.